# The perimeter of rectangle $A$ is $7$ times its width. If the perimeter of rectangle $A$ is $28$cm, find its length.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

I am so out of touch with my Maths! I am trying to help my daughter with her Maths, so any help would be truly appreciated.  Thank you very much in advance.

Question:  The perimeter of rectangle A is 7 times its width.  If the perimeter of rectangle A is 28cm, find its length.

Comment: (1) Draw a picture. (2) What is the width? (3) Write down the width beside the two relevant sides. (4) Now can you figure out the length?

Answer (score 1):

$P=2x+2y=7x=28$ so $$x=4$$ and $$y=\frac{28-8}{2}=10$$ Its length is 10cm.

Answer (score 1):

Let $w$ and $\ell$ be the width and length, respectively, of the rectangle. The perimeter of the rectangle is then $2w + 2\ell$, as can be seen by drawing a picture of the rectangle. We are told that the perimeter is 28, and so

$$28 = 2w+2\ell.$$

Now, we are given that the perimeter of the rectangle is 7 times its width. Symbolically, we have $28 = 7w.$ Dividing both sides of this equation by $7$, we obtain $w=4$.

We can then substitute $w=4$ into the equation $28 = 2w + 2\ell$, and obtain the equation $28 = 8 + 2\ell$. Subtract $8$ from both sides of the equation, and we have $20 = 2\ell$, and so $\ell=10$.